# Sort text-based information into different sheets

Tags: excel, sorting

I am creating a tracking document for artists' accommodation as part of an arts festival and would like to automate part of my work flow. Whilst we use event management/scheduling software for confirmed bookings, it's nice to do all my working in Excel.

I would like to have a master sheet (sheet 1), with a full list of artists and their respective accommodation - that can then be sorted into individual sheets (sheet 2, 3 etc) based on the name of the accommodation. The automatic sorting would also capture the other pieces of information in the row.

This would allow for each different sheet to show a report on who is staying in each type of accommodation and would be rather handy!

Comment: i am not able to understand what is the problem ? what you expect as an answer ? Are you able to create master sheet ? Can you show any example ?

Comment: Sorry, you're completely right - I've mocked up a basic document here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kowq1mx1y4rutmy/Accom-tester.xlsx

Comment: You need to use macro in excel for doing this, it can not be done using formulas. In macro, you have methods for creating new sheet, reading cell values, and writing them in another cell. I hope you have knowledge of excel macro and Vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend one or more PivotTables as a simpler solution. Here a PT and two clones are shown on your Master Sheet, but they could each be on their own sheet:

[image: SO19441597 example]

`Accom` is in Report Filter, `Company` is in Row Labels and `PAX` (as Sum) is in Σ Values. Once having clicked on PivotTable in Insert > Tables - PivotTable and having chosen you range ('Master Sheet'!$A$2:$C$7A2:C7) and Location just drag the fields from the big box to the little ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is feasible using Excel, but I don't recommend it; it is creating a maintenance nightmare in the long run.

From the question I can't gather whether the data is available in some kind of event management software package; if so you can use that one as a data source. Or create an Access or SQL database with a few tables. After that, you can use one of the following options to make the necessary overviews and as many more as you think up during the project:

1. Use Excel with ODBC or web query to retrieve data aggregated and
   sorted as you like. Make changes in the event management package
   allowing others to see the same facts. Or do it in Access. When you
   change one thing, it automatically propogates also into the Excel.
2. Similarly, you can use an Excel add-in such as [Invantive
   Control](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-control) (caution I work at a supplier) to retrieve the data from
   the database using SQL or a webservice, change it from within Excel and
   then synchronize the changes back assuming you have write access.
3. A similar solution is available as [SQL*XL](http://www.oraxcel.com/projects/sqlxl/index.htm). Probably there are others too.

If the solution must be Excel only, I would recommend using vertical/horizontal lookups with the Excel function `vlookup` / `hlookup` (Dutch: `vert.zoeken`, `horiz.zoeken`). These function perform reasonable with a small amount of data and performance can be improved by sorting. And they resemble SQL joins, so the database you get within Excel more easily conforms to the relational model.

I hope the event is successfull and the people enjoy it.